# Parse-server return 403 on XMLHttpRequest request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, xmlhttprequest, parse-server

I just installed parse-server for the first time and working with it. ( I'm not a stranger to nodejs though )
I managed to work with parse-server locally and I can use classes and save data in remote MongoDB without a problem.

But when I upload the codes on the server ( via Dokku ) the XMLHttpRequest returns 403 error.

I searched and tried many things but couldn't be able to solve this.

Appreciate some help.

Comment: 403 means you don't have access to the resource. Try to access the exact URL from browser and see if it works. You may also have a CORS problem.

Comment: directly it says : {"error":"unauthorized"}

Comment: I imagine that the problem has to do with authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't configured your ACL properly or not using masterKey.
parse-server has build-in authentication and ACL. you can override the ACL with 'masterKey'.

Comment: Thanks, I use the parse-server-sample so could you give me an example please.

Comment: Try this example as client, and check the official NPM page for how to set it on the server: curl -X POST \ -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: you_app_id" \ -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: your_master_key" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -d '{ "data": { "title": "The Shining", "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy." } }',

Comment: thanks Alon OZ, that helped me to run it manually on the server and it works alright. So I guess parse and dokku have some problems or I don't know how to config it.